# How to back-transform log data for standard error and confidence intervals?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, standard-error, lognormal-distribution

I'm using R to create graphs and run some stats. I find square root transformations are fairly easy to work with but for log transformations I'm having trouble understanding whether I'm doing it correctly or not. Is anyone able to help? Here are what my annotations look like:

> shapiro.test(final[which(Type=="DE")])

data not normal

> logde<-log(final[which(Type=="DE")])
>
> shapiro.test(logde)

p-value = 0.09358, transformed to normality: summarize log transformed data and back-transform to input into table

> summary(logde)

Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.

-5.7860 -3.3030 -2.7090 -2.6930 -2.0630 0.3318

> mean=10^(mean(logde))
>
> mean
>   [1] 0.002029606
>
> median=10^(median(logde))
>
> median
>   [1] 0.001954678
>
> sem=sqrt(var(logde)/length(logde))
>
> sem
>   [1] 0.04730152
>
> se.m<-10^sem
>
> se.m
>   [1] 1.115068

so far so good...right??
this is the part that I'm unsure about:

> leftCI=10^(mean(logde)-sem*2)
>
> leftCI
>
> [1] 0.001632333
>
> rightCI=10^(mean(logde)+sem*2)
>
> rightCI
>
> [1] 0.002523566
>
> leftCI=10^(mean(logde)-se.m*2)
>
> leftCI
>
> [1] 1.194744e-05
>
> rightCI=10^(mean(logde)+se.m*2)
>
> rightCI
>
> [1] 0.3447851

I have a feeling that my last two confidence intervals are done the right way? But can someone explain to me why I would have to back-transform my standard error before sticking it into the confidence interval formula when my means are still log transformed? Or maybe I'm doing this completely wrong but any help will be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Before you start transforming anything, are you referring to normality of your data? The data do not necessarily have to be normally distributed, the residuals from your models need to be normally distributed.

Comment: Hi Robbie, I actually realized that I don't necessarily have to normalize my data at all (so I gave up on this and just bootstrapped for my confidence intervals). Could you give me an example for "the residuals from my models"? I assumed I had to normalize the data to properly show the standard errors and confidence intervals in my summary table (but then realized that they wouldn't match my boxplots since I plotted my raw data and not the normalized data). I don't know why I thought all data in my summary table had to be normalized...